# How to give access to Multiple Firestore Documents for Specific Users through Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I want to give access to particular Document for a Specific user group. as shown in picture below. I want to give Access to **Doc1** & **Doc3** for **usergrp1** which is in **users** collection. How to do it with Firestore Rules.

**Documents collection**

[image]

**Users collection with groups docs**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to access other Firestore documents in the security rules for a given document, you should use the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get) and [`exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.exists) functions, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).

However, if you save each user of a group in a specific field of the "group" document (as we can see on the screenshots), you will encounter some difficulties because you need to know which field to be checked.

I would advise, to do as follows: for each user that is part of a group, use the user `uid` as the field name and assign a dummy value (e.g. `true` for example). Then you can easily check the field is present in the doc, as follows, for example, by using the `in` operator and the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get) function:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /docs/{docId} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/usergrp1).data
    }
  }
}
```

**However**, you can see in the above rule that there is a problem: the group name is hardcoded...

In order do have a group value for each specific document in the `docs` collection (e.g. `doc1` can allow be read by users of `usergrp1`), you need to save, in the document, the name of the group that can access it.

If you save the group name in a field named `authorizedGroup` you can adapt the rules as follows, by using a second time the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get) function:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /docs/{docs} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/docs/$(docs)).data.authorizedGroup)).data
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, i think its almost perfect, its returning data also, but i seems read stimulation failed

Comment: Hi Renaud, I'm following a similar example on the firebase docs here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access however after setting it up, trying to query the DB from the client side (js) fails as it says `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`. I've been told that the client side query needs to match the rules, but how can I query based on the above example or the example in the docs?